Why does my WebapplicationBuilder-API point not react?
I am working on my Bolero F# template and I try to write some API points to return certain information from my website.
I thought I start with 'minimal' APIs and I created this file for it:
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder()
let app = builder.Build()

app.MapGet("/api/HelloWorld", fun (context: HttpContext) ->
    context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!")
) |> ignore

app.Run()

At the front end you have your default Bolero code, plus one additional endpoint [<EndPoint "/Tax">] with other code I played around with.
With the default Bolero template, I get a website with the url http://localhost:5009, with three (or four endpoints in my case). Adding my helloworld-API should return me 'Hello World!' via the command-line for example in Powershell with Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:5009/api/HelloWorld" -Method Get but it doesn't. Instead I get the first page of the website.
Do I need to link these APIs somewhere in the frontend file?
